# Clearing a form and closing the div after successful post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that sends my form via php-ajax. It does return success but what I need it to do  when it has been successful is clear all the form data and close the div and load another one. I have tried many different ways to clear form and close div but they just seem to stop it working totally. The id of the div to close is '5box' The working script that i need to add these to is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');

                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevent default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;

    });
});
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the form you can call the `reset()` method of the underlying Element. I'm not sure what you mean by 'close the div', but you can call `hide()` to make it disappear. Try this:

```
success: function(result) {
  if (result == 'success') {
    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
    form[0].reset();
    $('#5box').hide();
  } else {
    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
  }
}
```

Also note that it would be much better practice to return JSON from the AJAX call. You can then have a boolean flag to show the state of the request.

*Update*

> `<button name ='send' value="Send" type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>`

Given that is the code of your button there is another issue - you're not preventing the form from being submit, hence the AJAX request is cancelled. To do this, hook to the `submit` event of the form instead of the click of the button. From there you can call `e.preventDefault()` to stop form submission. Try this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'success') {
            $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
            form[0].reset();
            $('#5box').hide();
          } else {
            $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note I used a generic `'form'` selector above. You can change that to a class or id selector on the form as required.

Comment: Hi, if i add both it stops working and if I add the .hide it doesnt hide it?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, is `#btn-finish` a submit button in a form?

Comment: You can use $('#5box').css('display','None') to hide the div.

Comment: @KhanjanBhatt you could, but it's bad practice to do it that way

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank for guiding me. Can you give me any reason for why should I not use this code?

Comment: You should avoid using the `css()` method unless absolutely necessary as it ties the CSS rules and JS code together when they should be as separate as possible. Use `hide()`/`show()` or any of the class amendment methods instead, such as `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks

Comment: <button name ='send' value="Send" type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>

Comment: @Jules thanks. I can see the problem now. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Do i not include the $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

Comment: You should include the document.ready handler, not the button click. I'll update the answer with the full code.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I have edited my answer above to include the code I mentioned

Comment: Sorry i have it, i get this' An invalid form control with name='email' is not focusable.'

Comment: Hi, ive just noticed, it sends the request twice?

Answer (score 0):

*For clearing form fields*

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Triggers as well

$('#form_id').trigger("reset");

Comment: Just FYI you can `edit` your answers to add more information.